# store an array to answer.json file which I created in bundle

Tags: arrays, json, swift

In my sample Xcode project I have created a json file called answer.json
and I want to write an array to it programmatically. please help me my array is

```
[["person": ["name": "Dani", "age": "24"]], ["person": ["name": "ray", "age": "70"]]]
```

---

```
 let fileUrl: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "answer",ofType:"json") as String!

 let personArray =  [["person": ["name": "Dani", "age": "24"]], ["person": ["name": "ray", "age": "70"]]]

 // Create a write-only stream
 guard let stream = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: fileUrl, append: false) else { return }
 stream.open()
 defer {
     stream.close()
 }

 // Transform array into data and save it into file
 var error: NSError?
 JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(personArray, to: stream, options: [], error: &error)

 // Handle error
 if let error = error {
     print(error)
 }
```

I want a json file in my bundle path with array data

Comment: Use `Documents` folder, you cannot add/update files in the bundle

Comment: #1 The application bundle is read-only. #2 Write `Data` directly with `write(to:`, not via a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in Document directory

```
guard let documentDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
    let fileUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("Persons.json")

    let personArray =  [["person": ["name": "Dani", "age": "24"]], ["person": ["name": "ray", "age": "70"]]]

    // Transform array into data and save it into file
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: personArray, options: [])
        try data.write(to: fileUrl, options: [])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```